# Can this motor shield be used with a raspberry pi and not an arduino?

Tags: arduino

Is it possible to wire this motor shield designed for the Arduino up and get it to work for a Raspberry Pi 2?

http://linksprite.com/wiki/index.php5?title=Motor_Shield

Comment: You can get suitable L9110S or L298N based motor driver boards for a couple of GBP from eBay.  That is what I'd do if I didn't already have such a shield.

Comment: Yeah, I was planning on doing that, I had already picked this one for something else. Didn't want to waste it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that it can. The arduino produces 5V logic levels whereas the RaPi only uses 3V3 so that's the main worry but, the L298 spec (the H bridge device used on the shield) I believe allows TTL high levels of 2V to be used.

OK I've just checked and the high logic level requirements are a minimum level of 2.3 volts so either 3V3 logic levels or 5V logic levels are compatible.

Regards the efficacy of this shield, take a look at the L298 spec or read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/what-h-bridge-drivers-are-preferred-for-applications-controlling-a-low-voltage-m) question on SE.EE

Comment: As a novice, is this an achievable thing to do?

Comment: I don't know - I'm not a novice and can't wear your shoes - what would seem easy to me might be a nightmare to you.

Comment: Sure, I can see where you're coming from. Any docs or anything that would point me in the right direction would be much appreciated. - Just seen your edit, cheers!